# Rearranging an equation to solve for a variable

Tags: cycloid

In the equation below, I need to solve for $t$. Can anyone assist with rearranging the equation?  My algebra skills have wilted over the years as I spent more time in front of engineering / CAD / GIS applications. Thanks!

$$
s=4r(1-\cos\frac{t}{2})
$$

Comment: t=2*arccos[1-(s/4r)]. I guess someone can post an answer with Latex formatting.

Comment: By the way, you may find the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) useful, particularly the Equations section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
s = 4r\left(1-\cos \frac{t}{2}\right)
$$
$$
\frac{s}{4r} = 1-\cos\frac{t}{2}
$$
$$
1-\frac{s}{4r} = \cos\frac{t}{2}
$$
$$
\arccos \left(1-\frac{s}{4r}\right) = \frac{t}{2}
$$
$$
2\arccos \left(1-\frac{s}{4r}\right) = t
$$